# accessing elements of an array of linked lists in main based on a list class

Tags: c++, arrays, list

I have a list class defined, with a private node struct in it. I'm trying to insert nodes into each index of the array, but its not outputting the list in cout at the end of the program. Is there a certain way to call the insert function on each row?

The program is supposed to take cards generated by this random generator and put them in the right index of the array 0-4, which is the suit, each card that is taken in is put in the appropriate list in the array of linked lists.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const string face[] = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
                        "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" }; 
const string suit[] = { "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades" };

int nmax = 4;

string random_card(bool verbose=false) {
    string card;

    card = face[ rand()%13 ];
    card += " of ";
    card += suit[ rand()%4 ];

    if (verbose)
      cout << card << "\n";

    return card;
}

class list{
    private:
        struct node{
            node();
            int index;
            node *next;
            node *prev;
        };

        node *head;

    public:
        
        node *sentinel = NULL;
        list();
        ~list();
        void insert(int i);

    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const list &l);
};


ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const list &v){
    list::node *p = v.head->next;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        out << p->next; //now you can call list in cout << list and it will print whole list;
    }
    return out;
}



list::~list(){

}


list::list(){
    node* head = new node;
    head->index = -1;
    head->next = NULL;
}

void list::insert(int i){
    node *helper = new node;
    helper = head;
    if(helper->next == NULL){ //head condition no traverse
        node *p = new node;
        helper->next = p;
        p->index = i;
        p->next = NULL;
        p->prev = helper;
    }

    while(helper->next != NULL){ //let's traverse and find it
        helper = helper->next;
    }
    node *pp = new node;
    helper->next = pp;
    pp->index = i;
    pp->next = NULL;

    while(helper->next != NULL){ //traverse and find out if my card is here
        helper = helper->next;
        if(helper->index == i){ //if it's here, next is nothing; previous is last node
            (helper->prev)->next = helper->next;
            helper->next = NULL;
            helper->prev = pp;
        }
    } 
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){

    bool verbose = false;
    int seedvalue = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
      string option = argv[i];
      if (option.compare(0,6,"-seed=") == 0) {
        seedvalue = atoi(&argv[i][6]);
      } else if (option.compare("-verbose") == 0) {
        verbose = true;
      } else 
        cout << "option " << argv[i] << " ignored\n";
    }
    srand(seedvalue);
    
    list v;
    
    string card = random_card(verbose);

    list arrayoflinkedlists[4];

    int array[4] = {0};

    size_t num;

    stringstream ss;
    ss << card;
    string facer, suiter, buffer;
    ss >> facer >> buffer >> suiter;

    if(suiter == suit[0]){
        num = 0;
    }

    else if(suiter == suit[1]){
        num = 1;
    }

    else if(suiter == suit[2]){
        num = 2;
    }

    else if(suiter == suit[3]){
        num = 3;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 13; ++i){
        if(face[i] == facer){
            arrayoflinkedlists[num].insert(i);
            array[num]++;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(array[num] == 13){
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
            cout << v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So many things can go wrong that I don't even know where to start. E.g.: your `ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const list &v){` always prints address of third element in the list 4 times (I'm pretty sure it's not what you want). Your `insert` method always leaks and it creates 2 nodes in case `head->next == nullptr`. This condition `if(helper->index == i)` is always true in first loop iteration. In main you never modify `v` list.

Comment: Further issues: `array[num] == 13` can't ever be true. You never add anything to `v`. Your list has a `sentinel` member, which is never used and is public, for some reason. I susggest that you start with a smaller and simpler program to test only your list.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting any output because the program is segfaulting somewhere.

A good starting point can be to reimplement `list::insert`. Supposing you allow for duplicates in the list, you can:

- Use a helper node pointer as you are doing.
- Walk the list until you find whether the end of the list or an element with an index equal or bigger to `i`.
- Create a node and insert it carefully, e.g., checking for insertions at the front, at the front and with an empty list, at the end, or at the middle.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/1eE6YeP1e)

```cpp
void list::insert(int i) {
    node *helper = head;

    while (helper != nullptr and helper->index < i) {
        helper = helper->next;
    }

    if (helper == head) {  // insert at the front
        node *n = new node{i, head, nullptr};
        if (head != nullptr) { head->prev = n; }
        head = n;  // update head
        if (tail == nullptr) { tail = n; };  // and maybe tail
    }
    else if (helper == nullptr) {  // insert at the back
        node *n = new node{i, nullptr, tail};
        tail->next = n;
        tail = n;
    }
    else {  // insert at the middle
        node *n = new node{i, helper, helper->prev };
        helper->prev->next = n;
        helper->prev = n;
    }
}
```

Following with the recommendations, I think that structuring the program around a `random_card` function that returns a `std::string` is a bad idea. Instead:

- Make your faces and suits `enum class`es, and use a `Card` struct type to hold a face and a suit:

```cpp
enum class face{Ace, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King};
enum class suit{Diamonds, Hearts, Clubs, Spades};

struct Card {
    face f{};
    suit s{};
};
```

- Now, `random_card` just returns a random `Card`:

```cpp
constinit const size_t number_of_faces{13};
constinit const size_t number_of_suits{4};

auto random_card(bool verbose = false) {
    Card ret{};
    ret.f = static_cast<face>(rand() % number_of_faces);
    ret.s = static_cast<suit>(rand() % number_of_suits);    
    if (verbose) { std::cout << ret << "\n"; }
    return ret;
}
```

- This introduces some boilerplate because you have to implement the enum to string conversion.

```cpp
std::string_view to_string_view(const face& f) {
    switch (f) {
        case face::Ace: return "Ace"; break;
        case face::Two: return "2"; break;
        case face::Three: return "3"; break;
        case face::Four: return "4"; break;
        case face::Five: return "5"; break;
        case face::Six: return "6"; break;
        case face::Seven: return "7"; break;
        case face::Eight: return "8"; break;
        case face::Nine: return "9"; break;
        case face::Ten: return "10"; break;
        case face::Jack: return "Jack"; break;
        case face::Queen: return "Queen"; break;
        case face::King: return "King"; break;
        default: return {};
    }
}
std::string_view to_string_view(const suit& s) {
    switch (s) {
        case suit::Diamonds: return "Diamonds"; break;
        case suit::Hearts: return "Hearts"; break;
        case suit::Clubs: return "Clubs"; break;
        case suit::Spades: return "Spades"; break;
        default: return {};
    }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Card& c) {
    return os << to_string_view(c.f) << " of " << to_string_view(c.s);
}
```

- But it simplifies the rest of the code.

```cpp
    list decks[4];
    size_t cards_per_deck[4]{};

    for (size_t face_index{0}; face_index < number_of_faces; ++face_index) {
        auto card{ random_card(verbose) };

        if (card.f == static_cast<face>(face_index)) {
            auto suit_index{ static_cast<size_t>(card.s) };

            decks[suit_index].insert(card.f);
            cards_per_deck[suit_index]++;

            std::cout << to_string_view(card.s) << ": ";
            std::cout << decks[suit_index] << "\n";
        }
    }
```

- Finally, if you use smart pointers, you don't have to deal with allocations.

```cpp
class list {
private:
    struct node {
        node() = default;
        node(const node&) = default;
        node(node&&) noexcept = default;
        node& operator=(const node&) = default;
        node& operator=(node&&) noexcept = default;
        ~node() = default;

        node(face ff, std::unique_ptr<node> n, node *p)
        : f{ff}, next{std::move(n)}, prev{p}
        {}

        face f;
        std::unique_ptr<node> next;
        node* prev;
    };
    std::unique_ptr<node> head;
    node* tail;

public:
    list();
    ~list();
    void insert(const face& f);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const list& l);
};
```

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/4K4nvGPj7)